# List assignment for list with greater than three nesting

Tags: r, list, nested

I have not been able to find a fix for this error. I have implemented work-arounds before, but I wonder if anyone here knows why it occurs.

the following returns no error as expected

```
q <- list()
q[["a"]][["b"]] <- 3
q[["a"]][["c"]] <- 4
```

However, when I add another level of nesting I get:

```
q <- list()
q[["a"]][["b"]][["c"]]<- 3
q[["a"]][["b"]][["d"]] <- 4
```

> Error in q[["a"]][["b"]][["d"]] <- 4 : more elements supplied than there are to replace

To make this even more confusing if I add a fourth nested list I get:

```
q <- list()
q[["a"]][["b"]][["c"]][["d"]] <- 3
q[["a"]][["b"]][["c"]][["e"]] <- 4
```

> Error in `*tmp*`[["c"]] : subscript out of bounds

I would have expected R to return the same error message for the triple nested list as for the quadruple nested list.

I first came across this a few months ago. I am running R 3.4.3.

Comment: Strange that it accepts : `q[["a"]][["b"]][["c"]]<- 3` but immediately after that if you do `q[["a"]][["b"]][["c"]]` it gives `Error in q[["a"]][["b"]][["c"]] : subscript out of bounds` error.

Comment: Please check the `str(q)`.  You are creating a `list` with one element 'a'.  Then on subsequent assignment i.e. `[[b]] <- 3`, it is a named vector and not a list.  What is your expected structure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we check the `str(q)` from the first assignment, it is a `list` with a single element 'a'. On subsequent assignment, it is creating a named vector rather than a list.

```
q <- list()
q[["a"]][["b"]] <- 3
q[["a"]][["c"]] <- 4
str(q)
#List of 1
# $ a: Named num [1:2] 3 4
#  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "b" "c"

is.vector(q$a)
#[1] TRUE
```

If we try to do an assignment on the next level, it is like assignment based on indexing the name i.e. 'b' which is empty and assign value on 'c'.  The option would be to create a `list` element by wrapping the value with `list`

```
q <- list()
q[["a"]][["b"]][["c"]]<- list(3)
q[["a"]][["b"]][["d"]] <- list(4)
```

It returns the structure with 'q' as a `list` of 1 element i.e. 'a', which is again a `list` of length 1 ('b') and as we assign two values '3' and '4' for 'c' and 'd', it is a `list` of 2 elemeents

```
str(q)
#List of 1
# $ a:List of 1
#  ..$ b:List of 2
#  .. ..$ c:List of 1
#  .. .. ..$ : num 3
#  .. ..$ d:List of 1
#  .. .. ..$ : num 4
```

By this way, we can nest 'n' number of `list`s

```
q <- list()
q[["a"]][["b"]][["c"]][["d"]] <- list(3)
q[["a"]][["b"]][["c"]][["e"]] <- list(4)
```

Note:  It is not clear about the expected output structure

Comment: Thank you for your detailed/quick response. I believe I resolved this on an earlier occasion by assigning list b containing elements c and d to a new list a. 

Your solution is far better and works well iterating through a table and making a list from factors like year, month, location. 

list[[year]][[month]][[location]] <- list(some event), for rapid look up of some event.